# Using AppIndicators with the Qt framework

Tags: indicator, application-development, qt

Is there a class or library somewhere that makes it easy to use the new [AppIndicator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) framework from within a Qt application?

It seems strange that I should have to include GTK headers / libraries etc. just to create an indicator in Qt.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

appmenu-qt is about exposing the menubar of Qt/KDE applications so that it appears in Unity panel. It is not about appindicators.

There is no explicit API to use appindicators from a Qt applications now. There should be one for Ubuntu 12.04. Until this is available, the two possible solutions are:

- Use the QSystemTrayIcon and ensure your users install the [sni-qt](https://launchpad.net/sni-qt) package (sni-qt transparently turns a QSystemTrayIcon into a StatusNotifierItem|AppIndicator)
- Use the KStatusNotifierItem class from kdelibs

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is finally a great answer to this:

On Launchpad, there is a package that provides a Qt class for setting a QMenuBar as an AppMenu:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt