# How to make an indicator for Ubuntu? (Because tray is useless )

Tags: indicator, qt, ide

So as more of you know, ubuntu has dropped the whole thing about tray and bringed something new called indicators.. As far as i know Qt Creator (IDE) is able to make only a tray and not an indicator (Just to mention there is a package in ubuntu called sni-qt which comes preinstalled, that can show tray icons but they lose a lot of their abilities like left clicking, scrolling at tray and others )..

I think the same question was asked here ([Using AppIndicators with the Qt framework](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40145/using-appindicators-with-the-qt-framework)) and one of the answers was for this package (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt).. With this package will i be able to create indicators with Qt? (If yes how?)

If i am not able to create an indicator with Qt, should i use a more native IDE to create an external executable which only thing it does will be to show the indicator? If yes, will that one be with Quickly? If yes could u give one-two links to help me create an indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have a much easier time creating an app indicator with GTK. After all, App Indicators are a GTK thing.

Creating an app indicator is very easy, it only takes a few lines of code. Have a [look here](https://bitbucket.org/Anay/buildnotify/src) for a Python answer that uses QT and an app indicator in a very nice and easy to use manner.

There is also [this link](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) that has several examples in various languages.

Don't forget you can always look at the source code of an app indicator that you use and like, and see how that works.

Comment: App indicator's aren't a GTK only thing!

Comment: Never said they were, just that they started there. First link is even a QT app indicator.

Comment: I cannot install the python example because (E: Unable to locate package pytz) so if i try to install the example ( ImportError: No module named pytz )...Any ideas? Ubuntu 12.10 here.. Also my qt project is in c++, will i be able to implement somehow the indicator?

Comment: I don't see a c++ binding for app indicators but there may be one out there. As for pytz, you need the lib `apt-get install python-tz` I think.

Comment: dead links ....